# Eclipse plugins for working with Apache Wicket projects

Tags: eclipse, wicket

Are there any widely adopted, currently maintained Eclipse plugins for working with Apache Wicket projects?  If so, where are they?  Who maintains them?  What do they do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard used to be [wicket bench](http://www.laughingpanda.org/mediawiki/index.php/Wicket_Bench), but it has been discontinued and you can find a fork named [stump](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/stump/wiki).

I don't know stump, but wicket bench mainly had a refactoring listener (if you rename a java class, the HTML is also renamed) and some wizards (create a Panel with associated markup etc).

I haven't used bench in years, as it was rather buggy in newer eclipse versions. But I have made pretty good experiences using a custom set of eclipse HTML templates that you can download from this location: http://www.wicket-praxis.de/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/wicket-template.xml
(German) description on this page: http://www.wicket-praxis.de/blog/download/

You can install these as HTML Code Templates in Eclipse:

```
Window -> Preferences -> Web -> HTML Files -> Editor -> Templates -> Import...
```

and that will enable wicket-specific template shortcuts in the HTML editor.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at Qwickie (eclipse plugin): https://github.com/count-negative/qwickie

Comment: yep, this plugin is great and is actively maintained (in contrast with wicket-bench)

Answer (score 2):

It's too bad you don't use IntelliJ IDEA.  It has an excellent plugin called [WicketForge](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?id=1545).

Comment: Excellent? More like rudimentary and passable at best. Or well, maybe I'm saying this because it wouldn't easily work for me, and I soon lost interest in it. In any case, I wish JetBrains added built-in Wicket development support in IDEA some day.

Comment: The reason may have been that we prefer to keep Java sources and HTML files in separate trees, and only put them together at compile time. An *excellent* plugin would surely support this.

Comment: WicketForge has supported separate Java / HTML trees for years.

Answer (score 1):

Not right on the question, but not completely off it, either.

I have released a tool that can be used as an eclipse save action. It generates Java interfaces with constants for ids in wicket templates and resource keys from translation files, so that you don't need to use strings for component ids and translation keys, but can use these generated constants.

It can be integrated in eclipse quite simply as an annotation processor. After a save of a component the interfaces will be generated and built. See its readme:

https://github.com/neurolabs/wicket-id-bindings-generator

I'm maintaining it on github (feel free to fork/contribute) and am using it in all of my wicket projects.